# My white wine has stopped fermenting, how can I restart it?

Tags: wine

My white wine fermented successfully  for a few days in a bucket. I've transferred it to a joram and it's stopped. Can I restart it somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to restart it?

Comment: Have you checked the specific gravity?  I would guess that it is done fermenting.

Answer (score 2):

As Jeff said, check the specific gravity. I've had batches that seemed to be stuck, that turned out to be finished when I checked the sg. Depending on the temperature, it can take a relatively short time for fermentation.I've had a 5 gallon batch ferment out to below 1.009 in three days, when the temperature was about 74F. Not a suggested temperature, but it was what happened. The wine still turned out ok. but wasn't one of my better efforts. Used it a lot in cooking.

If the sg is where you want it, then bottle it. If not, then repitching with some yeast that has some yeast nutrient added to the activation mix, and you should be ok.

Comment: do you mean 1.009?